# What JOIN types can be simulated with CROSS JOIN?

Tags: sql, join

The Wikipedia article [reads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) about `CROSS JOIN`:

> The results of a `CROSS JOIN` can be filtered using a `WHERE` clause,
> which may then produce the equivalent of an inner join.

Are there any other types of joins that can be simulated with `CROSS JOIN` and `WHERE` (or possibly some other construct)?

Comment: I would go on a limb here and I would say "no". Cross joins combined with WHERE were the old way of implementing inner joins, back in the 80s.

Comment: @TheImpaler This looks unexpected on the first glance considering a cross join produces all combinations of rows from the tables.

Comment: Inner joins can be simulated with cross joins. Other types of joins such as outer joins, or lateral joins, or the mythical union-join cannot, since they are not based in the cross product of rows.